# Android - THREAD_PRIORITY_FOREGROUND vs startForeground

Tags: android

Background: When using startForeground() command in android the user must see a notification describing that your app runs in the foreground.

my issue:
Instead of calling startForeground in my service to have android maintain my service as a foreground service with that notification that appears I am considering to use the following [command](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#setThreadPriority(int,%20int)):

`android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_FOREGROUND)`. I was hoping this will tell the OS to allow my app to live longer and then it would not show that notification warning to the user, are they close in behavior ?

Comment: This blog may help you. https://medium.com/google-developers/who-lives-and-who-dies-process-priorities-on-android-cb151f39044f#.o7k1hc2t1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> are they close in behavior ?

They are unrelated. `THREAD_PRIORITY_FOREGROUND` will tell the Linux kernel to give your thread more time on a CPU core. It should not have any impact on the lifetime of your process (or, if anything, it might shorten it, if you wind up consuming too much CPU as a result of the thread priority change and if Android takes CPU consumption into account for deciding which background processes to terminate when).

This is a case where a software development term ("foreground") is overloaded and has multiple uses.